# Uninstalling the currently active version of node.js with nvm

Tags: node.js, npm, uninstallation, nvm

On Ubuntu 16.04, I mistakenly used root to install nvm, and then to install node.js 8.8.1 via nvm. I also used `nvm alias default 8.8.1`, thinking it would correct my error.

Now I would like to:

1. Remove the default alias
2. Uninstall node 8.8.1
3. Uninstall npm 4.8.5, which came along with node
4. Uninstall nvm
5. Reinstall everything correctly for the right non-sudo user

It looks like I've succeeded with the first part:

```
# nvm unalias default
Deleted alias default - restore it with `nvm alias "default" "8.8.1"`
```

But nvm refuses to uninstall node 8.8.1, because it is the only version installed:

```
# nvm uninstall 8.8.1                                                                                                                             
nvm: Cannot uninstall currently-active node version, v8.8.1 (inferred from 8.8.1).
```

I am guessing that I first need to disactivate node 8.8.1, but I see nothing in the output of `nvm --help` which would appear to do this.

What steps do I need to take to completely remove node.js, npm and nvm from the machine before re-installing everything correctly?

Comment: Same question: [node.js - nvm: Cannot uninstall currently-active node version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38775287)

Answer (score 112, accepted):

In Terminal,
First type

```
nvm deactivate
```

Then type

```
nvm uninstall 8.8.1
```

Comment: Thanks @Shar. That nvm deactivate works. But why do we need to deactivate. It is not something like database server like PostgreSQL?

Comment: Thanks. This works for mac OS too. There are just two more steps if you want to completely remove everything related with nvm after this:  delete `nvm` related exports from your `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bashrc` file, and then delete `~/.nvm` directory.

Answer (score 15):

```
rm -Rf ~/.nvm
```

This is the nuclear option in my case. just -R would ask me if I really wanted to delete every file in the nvm folder.

Answer (score 9):

You can uninstall the nodejs by using the following command.

> yum remove nodejs

However, this will not remove the nvm from your linux box. To remove that try the below command.

> nvm unload

Answer (score 3):

```
nvm deactivate
```

can temporarily deactivate the nvm'ed node.
You can comment out the path in `.zshrc` etc, for the next session.

```
#export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
#[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
#[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried these commands for Ubuntu 20v and it removed node js completely

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then check version using, `node --version` and you will get this message,

```
bash: /usr/bin/node: No such file or directory
```