# Error npm is known not to run on Node.js v10.24.1 and how to fix it, don't update to the latest version?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I run : `npm run dev`

Error : **npm is known not to run on Node.js v10.24.1**

I have researched and know the command: `npm install -g npm@latest` and some other commands to fix the problem

But the problem is that my project is using `nodejs 10` so it can't use the latest nodejs. So is there any way to fix the above error. Thank you

UPDATE :
I use `nvm` to install and manage versions of nodejs. And my OS is macOs

Comment: I accidentally installed the `npm` package (and the `i` package) doing a mistaken `npm i package` command (probably `npm i npm i package`), also ending up with this issue :facepalm:

Answer (score 49):

The problem for me was upgrading my global version of npm while on an incompatible version of Node (8.16.1).

I tried to uninstall npm globally but that also didn't work because I could not use the npm command.

To fix it, I used nvm to switch to a compatible version of Node (`nvm use 14.0.0` - this can be any version of Node compatible with the npm version you have installed globally). This allowed me to run npm commands so I ran `npm uninstall -g npm` first of all to remove my global version of npm and then `nvm uninstall 8.16.1` to remove my faulty Node version.

May need to deactivate first: `nvm deactivate` https://stackoverflow.com/a/38776277/15435022

I was then able to reinstall Node 8.16.1 (`nvm install 8.16.1`), and with it came a fresh install of a compatible npm version.

Answer (score 39):

I performed an upgrade of npm by mistake and ran into the same issue.

The only way to solve for me was to delete the two following directories:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache
```

Comment: I just logged into stack overflow to vote for your answer. because its the valid tricky solution works for me too. tons of thanks

Comment: I did the same thing. Logged in to upvote this answer.

Comment: I faced to the same issue, this method is a bit brutal but at least it has solved my problem, thanks :)

Comment: Worked for me too. Upvoted.

Comment: This seems to have worked for me as well. I'm not sure why, but I suppose that matters less, as long as it works, which it did.

Answer (score 11):

I happen to work on a project that builds on `node 10` as well.

More details would have been helpful to understand the problem better but I suspect it's a compatibility issue.

Try these:

- Download and install the latest version of nodejs.
- Open you terminal and verify you have the latest version using `node -v`. Verify your npm version too using `npm -v`.
- Since you have `nvm` installed, run `nvm install 10`, then `nvm use 10`.
- Verify your versions again. In my case, `node` is `v10.24.1` & `npm` is `6.14.12`.
- Start your app using `npm run dev`. Please check you `package.json` to be sure you are using the right startup command.

Comment: how do you update npm?

Answer (score 11):

I was having the same problem, I ran the command and it solved the problem with NPM

```
sudo n latest
```

Node: v10.19.0
NPM: 8.9.0

[Reference](https://exerror.com/npm-does-not-support-node-js-v10-19-0-you-should-probably-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-node-as-we-cant-make-any-promises-that-npm-will-work-with-this-version/#:%7E:text=this%20version%20Error%20%3F-,To%20Solve%20npm%20does%20not%20support%20Node.,Your%20error%20must%20be%20solved.)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.
I was using node 12 with nvm

Then, I switched to node 16, uninstalled the version 12 with `nvm uninstall 12` and then I installed it again with `nvm install 12` and it is working fine

Answer (score 3):

npm is known not to run on Node.js v10.24.1 comes when normally people upgrade the version of npm to latest or recent ones, but when it comes to node 10 version you can use npm version 6.4.1 or 6 series. Normally npm 6.4.1 will come with node js 10.24.1 but if you have given any npm update cmd you need to go to C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming and delete npm and npm cache folders then delete npm folders in C:\Users\username\AppData\local then check the npm version using **npm -v**. After doing this install the angular version

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Oduola Olumide Sunday for the response. I have followed your way but still not solved the problem.

And I fix it by removing the latest nodejs version and using the normal **node v10.24.1**

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47251263/16562529) ->
I removed the latest nodejs version with this

Answer (score 2):

For [`nvm`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) used under macOS, I solve this issue in this way

First, run `nvm ls-remote` to get the latest version of `v10`

```
->     v10.24.1   (Latest LTS: Dubnium)
```

Then install the latest version of `v10` through

```
nvm install 10.24.1 --latest-npm
```

Comment: works like a champ...

Answer (score 1):

This error happens when your npm version is not what you think it is...

For instance, you download a nodejs pkg and install. Run `node -v`, `npm -v`... `npm -v` provides the error that brought you here.

This means your aren't using the version the nodejs pkg installed, but some remnant somewhere- *from other install attempts*.

In my case, I had a Homebrew installed version of npm that I didn't realize existed.

You can find the locations, at least on mac, using the 'where' command.

```
where npm
```

Which will return path(s) of your npm locations. Find the one that doesn't belong and give it the boot.

Then your npm -v will return the expected version number output.

Now you can execute npm commands.

Comment: LOL. This one just solved my issue- then I realized it was my post.

Comment: What did you mean by "give it the boot".

Comment: @ArnabDutta Sorry its an expression. Means to kick, to get rid off, delete, rm -rf.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone here needs to install an npm version (7.24.2) that does support node 10, rather than upgrade node.

Here is what I did:

```
url=`(curl -qSsL https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/7.24.2; echo "") | sed -e 's/^.*tarball":"//' | sed -e 's/".*$//'`
curl -qSsL -o npm.tgz "$url"
bin/npm-cli.js install -gf ../npm.tgz # in case npm is not installed where "which npm" points to, you might need to add --prefix=$(which npm | sed 's/\/bin\/npm//')
```

The reference is the installation script of 7.24.2 https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/v7.24.2/scripts/install.sh

Answer (score 0):

If you have used node as an npm, please upgrade to the expected version in the package.json file. Though you upgrade your node to higher versions, the version number that you give in the package.json takes precedence. Make sure correct version number is given in the package.json

Answer (score 0):

Downloading the latest node package from https://nodejs.org/en/download helped me resolve this error. There is a mismatch in Node version and the package installed in your system which is causing this error.